# Why is this phantom empty tag showing up in IE developer tools?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firebug, ie-developer-tools

There is a phantom empty tag (`<>`) showing up in IE's developer tools HTML tab.

Here's a snippet of the actual HTML source, with a few irrelevant portions removed:

```
<td><img src="1.jpg"></td>
<!--start mo script-->
<div id="mo">
<script type="text/javascript" src="mo.js"></script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('timeOutMO()', 5000);
function timeOutMO() { 
   document.getElementById("mo").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
<!--end mo script-->
<td><img src="2.jpg"></td>
```

In both Firefox's Firebug and Chrome's debugger, the nodes are shown as expected, with the `<td>`, `<div>`, `<script>`, and `<td>` nodes as siblings.

But in IE's debugger, I get a phantom empty node that's messing things up.  It looks like this:

```
<td>
   <img src="1.jpg">
</td>
<!--start mo script-->
<>
   <div id="mo">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="mo.js"></script>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
   <!--end mo script-->
</>
<td>
   <img src="2.jpg">
</td>
```

IE is basically treating the `div` and `script` inside the empty tag not as siblings of the `td` tags but as nephews and nieces.

Anybody know why?

Comment: I don't feel that downvoting him is particularly constructive. He has a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing violates the HTML standard. Every browser will handle strange cases like those differently. Why not wrap it in a td?

Comment: It's not my code.  It's a client's.  I'm just trying to work with it.

Comment: Yikes. What level of control do you have over it, then?

Comment: OK, so you're saying that the reason I'm getting the phantom tag is because the `div` tag and the `script` tag is between two `td` tags, and IE thinks that only a `td` tag should be between two `td` tags?  I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah. According to the HTML spec the only allowed tags inside a table row are a `td` or `th`. If anything different occurs, it's up to the browser devs as to how to handle it.